# Apache 2.4 rules, defaults and overrides for subdirectories with FilesMatch

Tags: apache2

I am having trouble understanding basic apache configuration.

I want to enable a set of defaults for all files and directories on the server but then enable/disable or modify them for certain files and/or directories.

The defaults I want are to deny access to all files on the server and to allow access to all directories below the web root (/var/www/html).

I want to allow access to certain files (that match a regex) in the web root and all subdirectories (which may be created dynamically in the future) and to allow access to certain files and/or directories from a given IP (or subnet) only.

All error pages (for files/directories that do not exist or are not allowed) are mapped to a simple string in localized-error-pages.conf.

I also want to disable directory listings for all directories but to show an index.html file if it exists.  For example I would like something like the following (all would show an error page if the file or directory does not exist or is not allowed):

```
example.com                # shows index.html in root
example.com/test.txt       # shows test.txt in root
example.com/test.php       # runs if IP matches
example.com/dir1           # shows index.html in dir1
example.com/dir1/test.txt  # shows test.txt in dir1
example.com/dir2           # shows index.html for dir2 if IP matches
```

If the root is /var/www/html, I want to do something like the following (on ubuntu in apache.conf), **NOTE this does not work**:

```
...
<FilesMatch "^.*$>
    Require all denied
</FilesMtch>
<FilesMatch "^.*\.(html|txt|pdf)$">
    Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^.*\.php$">
    Require ip 192.168.0.10
</FilesMatch>

<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
        Require all granted
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/htm/dir2>
    AllowOverride None
    Require ip 192.168.0.10
<Directory>
```

If I enter the address for the root or any subdirectory (without specifying index.html) I want to show the index.html for that directory if it exists or a default error page (mapped to a simple string in localized-error-pages.conf.  For example:

The problem is even after lots of searching and reading I don't understand how apache configuration works, especially with order of specifying rules and how they cascade to other directories; but I think a working example would help me understand.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Just a quick comment to say I have seen hundreds of examples of different configurations over the last few days, however they are all extracts showing only the relevant directive; I think the biggest problem is seeing exactly where in the apache.conf file all the pieces go; if anyone can give a small but complete file it would realy help.